# Can I get some product is virtual in Woocommerce by hook?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I custom a tab in panel (post.php page) like this:

[image]

But I want to hide it if it isn't virtual product.
And if it is virtual product, show it.

I don't know how can I get the value of product which is virtual or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this on product-page template  where you want to handle icon or tab:

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

    if ($product-> is_virtual('yes')) {
        // your logic to display tab or image etc 
    }else{
        // your logic not to display tab or image etc 
    }
    ?>
```

[follow this link for details](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productis_virtual/)

For more related details [see this link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-icon-if-product-is-virtual-or-downloadable/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199184/check-if-product-is-downloadable-in-woocommerce)

Hope this will give you idea and help!

According to comment to get product type with ID : [For details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576584/woocommerce-2-1-8-product-type-are-null)

```
$product = get_product(619);
echo $product->product_type;
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_virtual() on null

Comment: Thanks.I has already fixed this problem with your solution.
And reference this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576584/woocommerce-2-1-8-product-type-are-null

Comment: Thanks I have edited answer as per your comment and reference link !